# Adding a modal via js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that I want on every page. I was thinking of doing this via JS and then appending it to the body as opposed to adding it to every page. Would this be good practice? Or should I just add it to the page. Just seemed like a good way as opposed to adding it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Good ideas, but take it one step further by combining them into a single thing:

```
if(!modalOnPage) {
  addModalToPage
}
getPageModal.show
```

This way you only build it when necessary, and after that first build, you simply reuse it.